# Can I get Geojson from Google Earth?

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, google-earth

I am using Mapbox and the image of Disneyland Park is outdated (it changes to an old one when I zoom in closer) so I want to update it with a new image using a tileset on Mapbox. I get the geojson for Disneyland Park from geojson.io, but it uses OpenStreetMaps, which Mapbox also uses. On Google Earth the Map is updated. I am very new to Mapbox and geojson (very new with maps in general as well).

Can I get the geojson from Google Earth or is there another way to get the geojson from a more updated map (where Disneyland Park's image on close zoom is updated)?

First image is from Google Earth. Second one from Mapbox.

[image: Disneyland Park Google Earth]

[image: Disneyland Park Mapbox]

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON is a format used primarily for exchanging vector data (points, lines, polygons, etc.).

It sounds like you're trying to access the raster Google Earth basemap imagery, which is currently not available for download and viewing in other platforms.

Comment: Hey Gino thank you for your response. I managed to solve this issue by asking a professional surveyor to create an MBTile of Disneyland and I was able to upload it onto Mapbox. The surveyor has access to other Satellites where he could extract the MBTiles.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by asking a professional surveyor to create an MBTile of Disneyland and I was able to upload it onto Mapbox. The surveyor has access to other Satellites where he could extract the MBTiles.